# Bootstrap Navbar with other framework

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, navigation, navbar

I was just wondering is it possible to take just the bootstrap navbar sass files and use them if I already have a different css framework incorporated into my site? Or will it just conflict? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That should work given that html tags or class in your css files doesnot conflict with that in sass file

Comment: Thanks! Hopefully the file sizes aren't too large for just those elements!

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance of conflict on common name of bootstrap classes like `nav` `navbar` `card` etc which depend on the frame work which you were currently using.

The best solution is use custom `navbar` rather then some framework's.